# $(this).closest not working after div iteration

Tags: jquery

I am having the following problem:

When iterating through all of my divs to check if their waypoint attribute is equal to the one set in the as **startAddress** and
**destinationAddress**, ff there is no match out of all the waypoint items in the div, I want to hide the parent container (**rideshare-item**) and carry on. But if there is a match, I do not want to hide it.

Using `$(this).closest('.rideshare-item').hide();` doesn't seem to be working. Is there something wrong with my code?

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3kg160g/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Start:
        <br>
        <select class="form-control start-address">
            <option value="Lab">Lab</option>
            <option value="Hall">Hall</option>
            <option value="Apartments">Apartments</option>
            <option value="Church">Church</option>
            <option value="Park">Park</option>
            <option value="College">College</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-4">Destination:
        <br>
        <select class="form-control end-address">
            <option value="Lab">Lab</option>
            <option value="Hall">Hall</option>
            <option value="Apartments">Apartments</option>
            <option value="Church">Church</option>
            <option value="Park">Park</option>
            <option value="College">College</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="go-button">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row rideshare-item">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default rideshare-detail">
            <div class="panel-body"> <strong>Waypoints</strong>
                <br>
                <br> <span style="color:#449D44">Start</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Hall">Hall</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Apartments">Apartments</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Train Station">Train Station</span>
                <br> <span style="color:#c12e2a">Stop</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row rideshare-item">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default rideshare-detail">
            <div class="panel-body"> <strong>Waypoints</strong>
                <br>
                <br> <span style="color:#449D44">Start</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Lab">Lab</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Park">Park</span>
                <br> <span style="color:#c12e2a">Stop</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '#go-button', function (event) {
    // Collect values
    var startAddress = $('.start-address').val();
    var destinationAddress = $('.destination-address').val();
    // Only show matching pickup address and waypoint
    $('.rideshare-item').show();
    $('.rideshare-item .rideshare-detail .waypoint').each(function (a, b) {
        var waypoint = $(b).data('waypoint');
        if ((waypoint == startAddress) || (waypoint == destinationAddress)) {
            // do not hide div element
        } else if ($((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress)) && a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length - 1) {
            // hide div element 
            $(this).closest('.rideshare-item').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length - 1`

Comment: Your JSFiddle is broken (missing a closing `);`), otherwise I think it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e3kg160g/1/

Comment: @erkaner He doesn't know, it looks like the stackoverflow community is slowing building his project for him. Look at his post history. Which is fine I guess if you're actually learning.

Comment: @Jack - not at all. I've got a jsfiddle fork that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/5/. Only issue is that I can't seem to implement it into my code as I am a jQuery noob. All the solutions in the past posts were reflective of me trying to get it working. Alas, with little succes.

Comment: @methuselah I understand. I can just see it being hard for anyone to build upon code if they don't fully understand how that code they are building upon works. I don't see it as the best route to learn. I think that first comment was more hostile than I meant it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your JSFiddle is broken (missing a closing `);`)
- You also create a dummy jQuery object and test for true (which will always match) `$((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress))`

I also reversed your logic (hide first and show on match) to simplify it:

```
$('body').on('click', '#go-button', function (event) {
    // Collect values
    var startAddress = $('.start-address').val();
    var destinationAddress = $('.destination-address').val();
    // Only show matching pickup address and waypoint
    $('.rideshare-item').hide();
    $('.rideshare-item .rideshare-detail .waypoint').each(function (a, b) {
        var waypoint = $(b).data('waypoint');
        if (waypoint == startAddress || waypoint == destinationAddress) {
            // show div element 
            $(this).closest('.rideshare-item').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e3kg160g/6/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've been testing http://jsfiddle.net/e3kg160g/3/ - but Lab and College don't seem to work

Comment: @methuselah: Just noticed something odd in the conditional code.  `if ($((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress))` will always be true as that always creates a jQuery object based on a boolean!

Comment: I managed to do exactly that here: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/5/. This fork of code reproduces the desired results. Problem is, upon implementing it into my own work, I do not get the same results

Comment: @methuselah: Check out the simplified update above. I reversed the check (Hide all then show on match).

Comment: Thanks it works great. Also it has integrated perfectly with the setup I have here. You're a lifesaver!